# Magento 1.9 : Magereport warning 7405 not installed

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-7405

We have upgraded Magento to 1.9.3.4 and check in [magereport.com](http://magereport.com) , everything is fine but it is showing `7405 not installed`.

How can i solve this, please find the below screenshot:

http://prntscr.com/fvx810

Thanks

Comment: did patch had any issue when you applied? Is the applied patch under app/etc/applied.patches.list ?

Answer (score 0):

If you upgraded with patches then you can find the applied patches file *applied.patches.list* in the app/etc/ directory.

When patches are applied this file is automatically updated. Check if the 7405 patch appears in the applied patches list.

If you upgraded via the 1.9.3.4 source code or you can see the 7405 patch was installed then perhaps MageReport cannot detect this vulnerability status correctly due to a custom module as stated on the report page.

If this is the case confirm it by disabling the module and running the report again.

Answer (score 0):

I usually see "patch not installed" whenever I use CDN service like Cloudflare. If you have CDN enabled try disabling it temporarily, and do fresh scan on MageReport once again.

Answer (score 0):

You are upgraded to 1.9.3.4. It will included all security patches SUPEE - 9767 V2. Some time folder permission changes also show like that. Please check folder permission also.

You can also check SUPEE 7405 files updated in your files.

**Note:**

Magereport use behavior-based identification patterns. This is possible because each Magento patch introduces subtle changes in behavior. Apart from that, it is possible to request a few static files and derive the Magento version from that. check for more info [Github](https://github.com/gwillem/magento-version-identification).